# Delay a loop in timer

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I am using a loop in a timer and trying to add the delay in it.But it not working
.And I don't want to use Thread.sleep() because my UI will freeze

My code :

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
timer1.Start();
}
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DoStuff();
}

private void DoStuff()
{
     foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
     {
        if(item.subitem[1].Text == 0)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello")
            //Trying to add the delay here!!
          }

     }
}
```

I am trying to use `private async void DoStuff()`
and add `await Task.Delay(milliseconds);` to the loop too.But its not working because Timer1 will call `DoStuff` every Tick by ignoring the delay.(Tested Already)

The test code (Not Working) :

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
timer1.Start();
}
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DoStuff();
}

private async void DoStuff()
{
     foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
     {
        if(item.subitem[1].Text == 0)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello")
            await Task.Delay(1000);
          }

     }
}
```

My question is how can I add the delay in this loop by not moving all `DoStuff Code` to be in timer (Just add the delay by not changing the code position).

Comment: Show your await code.

Comment: @FrankerZ Ok Wait a sec.

Comment: Make the timer only tick once. At the end of the processing, change the time to tick once again.

Comment: If your UI freezes then you've implemented your code wrongly.

Comment: @KentKostelac Thread.sleep will freeze the main thread. In this question I mean I don't want to add another thread. Just only add the delay

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Is there another way? Because I use the timer to get the data. So the timer must Tick normally.

Comment: How often do you need to collect the data and how often should the the loop run?

Comment: @Eddga You don't have to add another thread. You just need define your methods as Tasks.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Every milliseconds. Because the data need to be update.

Comment: @KentKostelac Can you guide me how? Thank you.

Comment: @Eddga I will have an example ready in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Every millisecond can be quite difficult to achieve. I know no-one able to read at that speed. So, rethink your design: think about the data you need to collect and rethink when and how often you display the data. Just adding tasks and awaits is not going to cut it.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd. I know But I really need the timer to Tick like that because it will update the data in my ListView to be new data.By the way I want the project to be quicker than human. So I can't change the design. The design must be similar to this.

Comment: If you want the data collection to be fast, do not use any UI elements (such as the listview) in the processing code. Make a dedicated thread (or task) that continuously spins and collects the data. Use CancelationTokens or something similar to stop the thread when needed and sleep the thread for as long as required between data collections. That will be the fastest you can get it.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd. Yes I understood. But I need the ListView UI to be show up. Because user will see the data in that UI too.

Comment: Every now and then have the UI thread pull/copy data from the collection process. Because the user can not read 1000 updates per second you could limit that to, e.g., 60 times per second. That lower frequency would reduce the fighting of the worker thread and the UI thread over the data because there will be some sort of lock to protect the data from being read while being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote. You need to define your methods as tasks. The button code has a Task called DoStuff1. Also that means the button has to do be defined as async. Bascailly your entire issue is asynchronous programming(google that - there are many good examples out there). This way your UI wont freeze. And you can still use other buttons or texts in the UI.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<string> strings = new List<String>() { "Hello", "world", "!" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string returnString = await DoStuff1();
    }

    private async Task<string> DoStuff1()
    {
        foreach (string s in strings)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s);
            await Task.Yield();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        return "ASYNC DONE";
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]Like this?**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    List<string> strings = new List<String>() { "Hello", "world", "!" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        t.Elapsed += async (s, ev) => await DoStuff1();
        t.Start();
        //t.Stop(); //Stop immediately after and then you can add delays in DoStuff1() if you want to.
    }

    private async Task<string> DoStuff1()
    {
        foreach (string s in strings)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
        return "ASYNC DONE";
    }
}
```

Comment: This way might workng.But I need the Timer to call DoStuff(); I just done testing the code but the delay still not working

Comment: Updated with some new code. Now it just launches the method every 1000ms after the button being pressed once.

Comment: I appreciate your help. If I using this code to my design. Its not working. But I think I have to redesign my project.So I could use this guide.By the way this is my last choice.

Comment: This is your only correct choice. We don't create new threads and deal with mutexes in UI. We just use asyncronous programming or else the UI will freeze until the each method is done.

Comment: OK. If you say so.. I need to redesign my project. Thank you so much.